# Losing Internet connection randomly, fixed with ipconfig /release and /renew

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

I have been having intermittent internet problems in my room at my parents house for a few months now. Randomly the internet will just cut out, I can't load anything, and it gets fixed by running ipconfig /release and then ipconfig /renew. But I have to do this two or three times a day but its not a regular occurrence, so I have not found a pattern.

Things I have tried to do to fix it:

1) I restarted the router downstairs, this fixes it temporarily (in the same way the ipconfig /release and /renew fix the problem), so this is not a long term solution.

2) I am running a powerline connection to my room, so I have tried replacing the ethernet cables on both ends of the connection. I have not tried changing out the power line adapters but I do not think it will make a difference. I have been using the same adapters for a long time, before this problem started (but maybe they are the issue, I would love some guidance on this).

3) The problem happens on Windows 7 and Windows 10, and on two different motherboards, so I do not think it has to do with my computer itself.

4) I tried manually setting the DNS to 1.1.1.1 and 1.0.0.1 on both my computer and as the DNS for the router. This has not changed anything (although my latency seems better, so that's a nice bonus).

I have read a few of the similar questions on here about this problem but none of the solutions have helped me. The router was supplied by my ISP (Verizon Fios) and we have had it for a while now. There have been no recent changes to my internet connection, so I do not know what is causing this. Also I should note that no one else in my family is having this issue, but they are all using wireless. My computer is the only hard line connection in the house, so I think it has something to do with that.

I am open to any and all suggestions. If anyone has experienced this and fixed it (or even not fixed it) I would love to hear about it. Thanks.

Comment: do you think that the issue could be related to the wired ports or the cable is broken?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to determine if the powerline adapters are the issue. Can you move your system to either run it on wired or wireless? Assuming it doesn't drop, then the powerline stuff is likely an issue.
Or bring another pc to that area and hook it up to the powerline and see if it drops. 
When it drops, you do an ipconfig and does it show no ip address?
Try pinging 1.1.1.1 and see if it resolves as well.

Comment: Sounds like you have looped your network onto itself, creating the problems you have experienced. Do not set anything manually as that won't help. Set all machines to dhcp. You need to find where a network cable / powerline goes back into your network and this is a very easy mistake to make when powerline adapters are involved. You are best off completely unplugging everything and starting at the router, re-install. Start without powerline adapters and plug them in last.